# Iphone SDK- How to insert a banner in my app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, interface-builder

I have a tableview that my app shows when it loads, I would like to somehow put a banner at the bottom that if connceted to the internet will check my server for any new image files and if there are it will replace the current one and if not it will just leave it. That way I can constantly display messages to my users - sort of like in Doodle Jump.

How could I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask a more specific question because right now this reads like "please describe a complete implementation".

The basic outline might be (1) create a `UIImageView` in your view hierarchy (2) hook it up to your view controller (3) on view load, set `UIImageView` to the "current" image, possibly saved in the bundle, possibly saved in the application's Documents directory or temp directory (4) begin HTTP query to your server asynchronously and wait for the reply (5) save new image to file, and then and set `UIImageView` in reply handler.